# How to change text spacing for text in a Tkinter Label?

Tags: python, json, text, tkinter

I have a Label that needs to displaying the following information:

```
    json = {
        "H3": {
            "atom": "H3",
            "scheme": "NH3_ISA-GRID",
            "type": "HN",
            "rank": "4",
            "moments": [
                "          Q0        Q1        Q2        Q3        Q4",
                "0   0.353619 -0.000000  0.022593 -0.000000  0.016054",
                "1s       NaN -0.020984 -0.000000 -0.010761 -0.000000",
                "1c       NaN -0.009221 -0.000000  0.007970 -0.000000",
                "2s       NaN       NaN -0.016711 -0.000000  0.015248",
                "2c       NaN       NaN  0.016692 -0.000000 -0.009410",
                "3s       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.003688 -0.000001",
                "3c       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.025270 -0.000001",
                "4s       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.005240",
                "4c       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.010030"
            ],
            "file": "/Users/gianluca/Desktop/project/example_molecules/ISA/OUT/NH3_ISA-GRID.mom"
        }
    }
```

Note how the "moments" entry is properly aligned as a table.

This is what I have for trying to get this information into a Label:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("PyMolDat")
num = 0

json = {
        "H3": {
            "atom": "H3",
            "scheme": "NH3_ISA-GRID",
            "type": "HN",
            "rank": "4",
            "moments": [
                "          Q0        Q1        Q2        Q3        Q4",
                "0   0.353619 -0.000000  0.022593 -0.000000  0.016054",
                "1s       NaN -0.020984 -0.000000 -0.010761 -0.000000",
                "1c       NaN -0.009221 -0.000000  0.007970 -0.000000",
                "2s       NaN       NaN -0.016711 -0.000000  0.015248",
                "2c       NaN       NaN  0.016692 -0.000000 -0.009410",
                "3s       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.003688 -0.000001",
                "3c       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.025270 -0.000001",
                "4s       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.005240",
                "4c       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.010030"
            ],
            "file": "/Users/gianluca/Desktop/project/example_molecules/ISA/OUT/NH3_ISA-GRID.mom"
        }
    }

for k, v in json.items():
    for i, j in v.items():

        tk.Label(root, text=i, width=10, anchor="w", font="Arial 10 bold").grid(row=num,
                                                                                column=0, padx=10, sticky="ne")

        tk.Label(root, text=j if i != "moments" else "\n".join(j), width=65, anchor="w", justify='left').grid(
            row=num, column=1, padx=5)

        num += 1

root.mainloop()
```

and the resulting table instead loses the appropriate spacing, see image 1:

[image: image_1]

Any ideas on how to format the "moments" text block? Many thanks for your time and effort. I've just noticed the information in json isn't the same as image 1 but of course everything is the same, my bad, shouldn't change anything however.

Comment: Use monospaced font for moments values.

Comment: Change the font to a fixed width font supported by your PC. Courier New is the common one on Windows PCs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), e.g. `font=("Lucida Console", 10)`:

[image]